# django-tinymce: javascript error on console, tinymce widget not rendered

Tags: javascript, django, tinymce, django-cms, django-tinymce

i'm using django-tinymce in a django project. After following the setup as suggested from [docs](http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), i've experienced some problems while deploying it. In fact, with the same settings, with development runserver, I got it working locally, but on a test machine (NGinx + Gunicorn), i have this error on console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function tiny_mce.js:1
    k.create.init tiny_mce.js:1
    (anonymous function) tiny_mce.js:1
    (anonymous function) tiny_mce.js:1
    c.each tiny_mce.js:1
    o tiny_mce.js:1
    (anonymous function) tiny_mce.js:1
    p tiny_mce.js:1
```

In the best case I have only a basic textarea widget, in other cases i have no widget at all rendered. Anyone that have experienced that problem or any help?

Thanks,
LuKe

Comment: I hit a similar problem with what I think was a buggy version of django-tinymce - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238501/django-tinymce-in-django-admin-cant-find-variable-tinymce/14242114#14242114